# preview a vCard without adding it to the contact list

Tags: contacts, vcard

Is it possible to preview a vCard (placed online, as a file or QR code), the same way it's done for NFC?

How it works for NFC: https://youtu.be/NCkBAELTODk

Firefox just saves vCard silently, without asking any questions. Trying to open it with contacts asks where to import it.

Comment: vCards are plain text files, so you can directly open them with any text editor. There you will find details like Name & Number.

Comment: This question is not about how to read vCards, but how to preview it the same way as for NFC.